# How to find the number of divisors of a given number?

Tags: arithmetic

I am stuck on this question...please help me
 `

> **Find the number of divisors of $2^3 * 21^2 * 91^1$ excluding $1$ and the product itself.**

Please answer this and also tell me how to do it?

Comment: What are you stuck on?  Have you tried listing the divisors?

Comment: Sorry for bad English..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to completely factor the number into a product of prime numbers. By the product you listed, your number is 321,048.

Its prime factorization is given by: $321,048=2^3 \cdot3^2 \cdot 7^3 \cdot13$

For a number, $n=p^a$ where $p$ is a prime number, it has $a+1$ divisors ($1,p,p^2, ..., p^a$). For $n=p_1^a \cdot p_2^b$, it has $(a+1)(b+1)$ total divisors ($a+1$ options for a divisor coming from the first prime, and (b+1) for the second. Multiplying gives the possible combinations of them together).

At this point we can see the pattern: increment the power of each of the prime factors by 1, and multiply them together for the total number of divisors.

Moving back to your number, it has $4\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2=96$ total divisors. Removing 1 and the number itself, by your constraints, the answer is $94$ divisors.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems redundant to multiply out the factors completely, then factorize into prime powers.  Wouldn't it be quicker to simplify $21^2 = 7^2\cdot 3^2$ and $91 = 7\cdot 13$?

Comment: Totally redundant, for the sake of the writing something up in general I preferred to work with a number instead of a product.